# For loop in python for boolean field . Openerp 6.1

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean, odoo

I have raise a warning based on the value of the boolean field. But what is happening is even if my condition is satisfied, the error is raised when it should go in that if statement. Please help.

```
        for i in scm_brw.cust_search_line:
            if i.check==True:
                print "FIRST IF",i.check
                if i.con_check == True:
                    raise osv.except_osv(('Alert!'),('Migration date is already alloted'))
                self.pool.get('res.partner').write(cr, uid, i.id , {'m_date':scm_brw.migrate_date,'con_check':True})
            if i.check==False:
                print "SECOND IF",i.check
                raise osv.except_osv(('Alert!'),('Please select atleast one customer to migrate'))
```

Here is code.

Comment: Is `i.check` true or false? What about `i.con_check`? I'm not clear what you are expecting to happen and what is in `scm_brw.cust_search_line`

Comment: its i.check. if its true then no warning of  'Please select atleast one customer to migrate' should be raised. But I'm getting it. Nothing to do with con_check  that is diiferent

Comment: Are you certain that `i.check` is the boolean `True` and not the string `'True'`? Does you code print the "FIRST IF" stuff or the "SECOND IF" stuff?

Comment: FWIW, the normal way to write that sort of test is `if i.check: ... else:`. It's rare that you need to explicitly test against `True`.